# Binding a value from custom control to html control using angular 2 directives in typescript

Tags: html, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I have created a custom control directive as "my-text-box", inside this directive I am using html control `<input>`, I need to pass values from my custom control to html input control. In angular1 simply I am using like `<my-text-box id="1" name="Box 1">` using my custom attributes of scope variables in directive, i assigned the values to html control like `<input type="text" id="{{id}}" name={{name}} >` how can i use this scenario in angular 2.

Here is my sample code:

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TextBoxComponent} from './TextBoxComponentDirective';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1> <my-text-box id="66" name="MyText1"></my-text-box>',
  directives:[TextBoxComponent]
 })

export class AppComponent { 
title="Sample TextBox";
}
```

**TextBoxComponentDirective.ts**

```
import {Component,Input,Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'my-text-box',
    templateUrl: './TextBoxTemplate.html',
})
export class TextBoxComponent {

    @Input() id; 
}
```

**TextBoxTemplate.html**

```
 <input type="text" [name]="name" [id]="id"/>
```

Comment: In angular2, directive doesn't have a template meta property  as in Angular1. So code is needed and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @micronyks updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@Input()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) for this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-text-box',
    template: `
        <input type="text" [id]="id" [name]="name" >
    `
})
export class MyTextBoxComponent {
    @Input() id;
    @Input() name;
}
```

In your parent component you now can use it like so:

```html
<my-text-box id="1" name="Box 1">
```

Or if you need to bind to variables:

```html
<my-text-box [id]="someId" [name]="theBoxName">
```

---

> **Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wXiuATtDFnvCc0jOpnKV?p=preview) for example usage**

Comment: i tried with ur example but it shows id="undefined" name="undefined" in input control. see the my sample code

Comment: You could try `<my-text-box [id]="'66'" [name]="'MyText1'"></my-text-box>` with additional `'` around the strings.

Comment: I checked with a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wXiuATtDFnvCc0jOpnKV?p=preview) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: yeah i have seen, but in this case you have used a single ts file. but my side i need to use separate app and directive files.so that i can reuse this directive..

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, but I can seperate it out for your pleasure.